# How to show the button in dropdown event?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, drop-down-menu, textbox

Hai i have a button and dropdown.When i change the dropdown i hide the button its working fine.Event after i want to show the button.how to do this.

once i hide i cannot view the button.i need to hide only the dropdown change function other time i want to show the button.

**code**

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function(){
$("#myHeader").hide();
    });
});
</script>
<body>

<select id="header">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="button"  id="myHeader" style="width:20%;background-color:blue" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When do you want to hide the button? When do you want to show the button?

Comment: while change the dropdown i want to hide,After changing i want to show

Comment: You have 3 values in your drop down, you want to hide when you choose 1,2 or 3, you want to show when you select 1,2 or 3? Or you want to show/hide every other time not depending on the value selected?

Comment: when i click the dropdown i want to hide the button othertime i want to show

Comment: you hadn't mentioned that mobile support is needed!

Comment: sorry how to do this in android phonegap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$("select").focus(function(){
     $("#myHeader").hide();
});

 $("select").blur(function(){
     $("#myHeader").show();
});

$("select").change(function(){
     $(this).trigger('blur');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TjZSu/)

Comment: Nothing happened in this demo

Answer (score 0):

Change your script as per below, It will create toggle type event

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("select").change(function () {
            ($("#myHeader").is(":visible")) ? $("#myHeader").hide() : $("#myHeader").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Let me know weather you were looking for this type functionality?

Comment: once i hide i cannot visible it again

Comment: After changing press CTR + F5 because it is working here, also you can try toggle event as per this link http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: when i touch the dropdown i want to hide the button othertime i want to show

Comment: please look at this http://jquerymobile.com if you want to do for mobile specific.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `.change()` then, your question/code is confusing.  I think this is what you're looking for:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     $("select").focus(function(){
         $("#myHeader").hide();
     });

     $("select").blur(function(){
         $("#myHeader").show();
     });

 });
```

Review this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yRmH8/1/) and let me know if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: when i touch the dropdown i want to hide the button othertime i want to show

Comment: When you click or when you change?  It's not easy understanding your request you know.. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: when i click the dropdown i want to hide the button othertime i want to show

Comment: Instead of `.blur` try `.change` or `.select` to see if it's what you're looking for, I can't really understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13545/discussion-between-user1324068-and-zee-tee)